# Installing OpenProject without SSH

Tags: openproject

I'm trying to install OpenProject on to a shared server space with 1and1. I don't have root access so can't use the [installation guide](https://www.openproject.org/download-and-installation/). My servers running Debian.

Is there any method of installing from an archive?